# Sidemenu customization

Tags: codenameone

I am interested in customizing the side menu. I would like to draw a shadow over the "previous screen" that had slid right when a hamburger / side menu opens.

Is there currently a way to accomplish this?

Here is a screenshot of what I would like to accomplish:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What would be nice if there was the equivalent of `Dialog.setDefaultBlurBackgroundRadius(8);` for SideMenu

Comment: I was thinking more about it , I think there is a way to implement it. All I have to do is likely catch the event that the side menu is being open. At that instance , "darken" the current form. Then again, catch the event when the side menu is closing , also at that instance undo / remove the overlay. Will give that a shot this afternoon

Comment: I tried to use form.setTintColor(0x333333) to darken the screen but it doesn't seem to work for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that pretty easily. Style the `SideNavigationPanel` UIID to white to create the background color, make sure it's opaque (bg transparency == 255).

You can add side commands with material icons using `addMaterialCommandToSideMenu` from the `Toolbar` class. However it will set the same color to both the icon and the text so an alternative would be to use an icon from `FontImage` or elsewhere.

The separator can be added like we do it in the [new kitchen sink](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/kitchensink-ii.html):

```
    Label separator = new Label(" ");
    Style separatorStyle = separator.getAllStyles();
    separatorStyle.setBgImage(Image.createImage(40, 2, 0x7f000000));
    separatorStyle.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_TILE_HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_CENTER);
    separatorStyle.setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    f.getToolbar().addComponentToSideMenu(separator);
```

Comment: Hi Shai, I think you misunderstood the question, he was asking about sliding the sidemenu over the current form, instead of pushing the form away.

Comment: That is correct. I was mainly asking about the dark "overlay" that appears on the previous screen once the side menu is open. In the attached image above, I had dropped a comment in red with an arrow pointing to that overlay. I am not very particular about sliding the side menu over the current form vs moving the current form right while the side menu opens. Either way works for me. But once The side menu is open I would like to draw a dark overlay  so it is visually more clear that the previous screen is no longer in focus

Comment: You can override the forms paint method and use the `SideMenuBar.isShowing()` method to determine whether tint should be rendered.

Comment: I tried calling form.setTintColor(0x333333) to darken the screen but it doesn't seem to work for me (no effect seen). Did I use the wrong method for this case?

Comment: Side menu isn't a dialog so it won't change anything for this case. Side menu is a pretty special case in many aspects so a lot of the usual tricks won't work.